# What programming paradigm/metamodel characterizes D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, chaining, dataflow, metamodel, paradigms

While D3 is marketed as a "web graphics library", that doesn't really reveal what programming paradigm/metamodel it is based on. What is that paradigm? Is it simply a dataflow programming library for javascript (which is imperative in nature)?

I understand "how" its statements are structured: fluent method chaining which takes data in, and transforms it into some other textual format (namely a Document Object Model).

This sounds a lot like dataflow programming / functional programming / UNIX pipes and filters. Is this the closest conceptual programming metamodel to describe D3.js?

Comment: "An embedded domain-specific language [16] for transforming
the document object model based on data."  http://vis.stanford.edu/files/2011-D3-InfoVis.pdf

Comment: http://blog.sleptons.com/2015/01/functional-programming-d3js-good-example.html

Answer (score -1):

Simply, I concluded that d3 js is mainly follows the idea of functional and like jQuery chaining pattern. Almost, every function returns some object with some binding methods in d3.So, If you want to learn d3.js you need to know the modules involved in d3 js and know each of that functionalities. That is enough

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more conceptual with big words that I could google around for (ideally something like martin fowlers articles). Maybe there's little more to it than chaining, but I'd be disappointed with the authors of d3.js if there wasn't more to its design.